# HTML/CSS Why does my style file not respond

Tags: html, css

My styles.css doesen't seem to be working,

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
 <main>  
    <div class="tribute">
      <h1>Alexander Fleming</h1>
      <p>Pioneering Penicillin Scientist</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgp">
    <img class="fleming"src="https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/183FB/production/_113832399_aleksandarflemingsasuprugom1954.jpg" alt="Alexander Fleming and his wife">
   <p>The man who saved millions of people, Alexander Fleming</p>
</div>

</main>
</body>


</html>
```

```
.tribute{
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid red;
}

h1{
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Everything is fine and the .css  file has the same name, in the same folder and everything, I tried setting the border to h1 and .tribute class and its not working, if I put the  element its working, but its not working when I do it in the .css file please help!

EDIT: I checked the charset and everyting seems to be fine I dont know what seems to be the problem, maybe its my link rel?

EDIT2: I fixed the problem, the problem was the LivePreview it was not working for some reason so I opened it on chrome and I saw the style was working so if anyone else has the same problem try opening the html file in the Browser!

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @ralph.m Well the css file I tried adding padding and everyting and its not "moving"

Comment: @Austin how do I check that??

Comment: @MentalBoolean I cheked and its not that

Comment: @SpirtMass: Now is a great time to start using your browser's debugging/development tools.  You can use the Console tab to check for errors, use the Network tab (when loading the page) to see if a request is made for the CSS file and what is the server's response, use the DOM Explorer to examine elements and observe the exact style rules applied to each element, etc.